# Don't see cloud messaging service in google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I added FCM through firebase console, but it fails to receive messages on device.

I found that even though I added FCM to project I do not see any `cloud_messaging` service in `google_services.json` downloaded from console.

Question is does Firebase add any cloud services in this json?
How do I confirm if FCM is added successfully?

`"services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }`

Comment: did you download the new json file that firebase generated after you added fcm?

Comment: You must keep in mind that to receive Messages sent from Firebase Console, App must be in the background, not started neither hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The `cloud_messaging` tag is not present inside the `google_services.json` file.

You must keep in mind that to receive Messages sent from Firebase Console, App must be in the background, not started neither hidden.

Further, please check whether your manifest file is having this snippet:

```
<service
android:name=".NotificationGenie">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you @iamgopal for confirmation that `cloud_messaging` need not be in `google-services.json`. 
I have these services declared in manifest as per documentation.
Finally I am getting notifications now

Comment: @Prakash that's amazing. Please upvote and accept if it helped you in any way. It encourages more to help the community. :)